# How to value smoothness of a dataset?

Tags: statistics, curves

I have a dataset, which I can see the occurance of different `angle` of wind speed each year, like this:

[image]

But the dataset is not very clean, sometimes, the distribution would look like:

[image]

Notice the angle(x-axis) ranging from `260-320`, it's not as smooth as the above plot.

I'm wondering if there is an indicator that I can use the measure the `overall smoothness` of such distribution? So I can know when the data is corrupted and need corretion.

What I can think of is to calculate the difference of each bins.

BTW: What tag should this question belong to?

Answer (score 1):

A first approximation would be to calculate the variance of the differences between the samples. Assuming your values on the y axis are $y_0, y_1, ..., y_{36}$, you would get $$\overline{Var}(\Delta Y) = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i \in {0,...,35}}((y_i - y_{i+1})-\overline E[\Delta Y])^2 $$.

Second and probably much more exact method is to fit e.g. a $sin()$ model to the data (either for each year or for the whole population) and then calculate the difference from that model to each $y$.

Comment: yes, for the first, a `constant line` would be smoother than `sin`.